# Dynamic property inside the wkt:// on Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld

I try to create dynamic symbolizers with WKT. This [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html#dynamic-symbolizers) says a CQL expression can be used inside a WellKnownName or a link:href. I want my symbolizers to have a dynamic size depending on my data on postgis.

Here's my SLD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Real Size</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Real Size</Title>
      <Abstract>Real Size</Abstract>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>container</Name>
   <ogc:Filter>
     <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:PropertyName>ct</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Literal>container</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   </ogc:Filter>
<PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
 <Graphic>
    <Mark>
      <WellKnownName>wkt://POLYGON((0 0,${length}/1.5 0,${length} -${width}/2,${length}/1.5 -${width},0 -${width},0 0))</WellKnownName>
      <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#0000ff</CssParameter>
      </Fill>
      <Stroke>
        <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000ff</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">100</CssParameter>
      </Stroke>
    </Mark>
    <Size>600</Size>
  </Graphic>
```

The error I've got is :

> Rendering process failed The specified mark "wkt://POLYGON((0
>   0,${length}/1.5 0,${length} -${width}/2,${length}/1.5 -${width},0
>   -${width},0 0))" was not found!

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to pass dynamic attributes into my graphics? (like SVG?)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

`<WellKnownName>wkt://POLYGON((0 0,${length/1.5} 0,${(length -width)/2} ${length/1.5 - width},0 -${width},0 0))</WellKnownName>`

In other words, keep expressions fully parenthesized, only what's inside `${...}` will be evaluated, the rest is entered into the well known name string as is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll remember that rule ! Anyway I still have the same issue, I've found a workaround drawing my symbols with openlayers in svg but I let that question open, I think this could be a nice feature

Comment: For those that came here trying to find out how to parameterize all the SLD (as me), you must use ```PropertyName``` if you are outside the WKT definition: ```<Rotation><ogc:PropertyName>bearing</ogc:PropertyName></Rotation>```