# Access and change SLD elements by code

Tags: sld, geotools

Lets say we have this SLD in a file called "vessel.sld":

```
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Vessel Layer</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>GeoServer SLD Cook Book: Rotated square</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#009900</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>12</Size>
              <Rotation>45</Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
```

Now I load it using this code:

```
try {
     SLDParser parser = new SLDParser(  CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory() );
     parser.setInput( new File("vessel.sld") );
     StyledLayerDescriptor sld = parser.parseSLD();
     Style[] style = parser.readDOM();
            
            
      ???
            
            
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there some way to access and change its attributes/values ( like "rotation" for example) or even modify the whole SLD by code?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution besed on [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217046/dynamic-property-inside-the-wkt-on-geoserver):

First prepare the geometry:

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
builder.setName("Vessel");
builder.add("coordinates", Point.class);
builder.length(15).add("shipName", String.class);
builder.add("mmsi", Long.class);
builder.add("lat", Float.class);
builder.add("lon", Float.class);
builder.add("length", Float.class);
builder.add("width", Float.class);
builder.add("bearing", Integer.class);
this.VESSEL = builder.buildFeatureType();
```

Now create the SLD with variables :

```
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>wkt://POLYGON((0 0,${length/1.5} 0,${(length -width)/2} ${length/1.5 - width},0 -${width},0 0))</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#009900</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>12</Size>
              <Rotation>0</Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
```

Assign:

```
Style style = getStyle( this.config.getString("vesselStyle") );
this.vesselLayer = new FeatureLayer( this.vesselCollection, style );
this.vesselLayer.setTitle("Vessel Layer");
this.map.addLayer( this.vesselLayer );
```

Now I can fill these values when create the Feature:

```
Point point = this.vesselGeometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("coordinates", point);
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("lon", x);
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("lat", y);
        
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("length", 100);
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("width", 30);
        
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("bearing", bearing);
this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("mmsi", mmsi);
        
SimpleFeature aVessel = this.vesselFeatureBuilder.buildFeature( String.valueOf( mmsi ) );
```

Here "100" and "30" will replace "${length}" and "${width}".

Easy!!

Comment: In fact this won't work for attributes like Rotation.. seems I can only use this method inside the WKT definition. To use it inside the SLD body I think we need the PropertyName tag. ```<Rotation><ogc:PropertyName>bearing</ogc:PropertyName></Rotation>```